# Dictionary assignment crashes Cython

Tags: python, cython

The cython code below crashes due to the `word_idxs[token] = row` statement. If I remove that statement everything works fine. Here are my observations

1. The code works fine when a different file is given as argument
2. I tried printing `token`, the program crashes for different values of `token` at different times (it is not the particular word that is causing the error)
3. I tried assigning `word_idxs[row]=row` and the error persists. So I think the error has nothing to do with strings in particular
4. If I keep assigning to the same key, the error does not occur. eg : `word_idxs['constant'] = row`
5. If I remove `cmatrix[row, col] = fval`, then again everything works

I am new to Cython, please do point out if I'm doing something fundamentally wrong

```
 def cload(self, file_path, int dim, long vocab_size):
    print("Loading")
    cdef:
        unsigned int row = 0
        int col = 0
        float [:,:] cmatrix
        cdef dict word_idxs = {}
        char* token
        char* line

    matrix = np.zeros([vocab_size, dim], dtype=np.dtype('f'))
    cmatrix = matrix

    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        for line in f:
            token = strtok(line, ' \n')
            print(row, token)

            word_idxs[token] = row

            for col in range(dim) :
                val = strtok(NULL,' ')
                fval = atof(val)
                cmatrix[row, col] = fval
            row += 1
```

Comment: I've downvoted because this isn't a minimum, complete, verifiable example. It would not be possible to reproduce your bug with the code you provide.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious issue to me is that you have no error checking on the output of `token` or `val`. It can be `NULL` if `strtok` reaches the end of the string and you just don't deal with this. Because of the lack of verifiable example it's difficult to know what the actual issue is

There's then a couple of issues that @ead pointed out in the comments:

1. Python strings are supposed to be immutable but `strtok` modifies the pointer it's given. That's unlikely to cause the crash you see but could cause issues with Python.
2. `line` is most likely an invalid pointer as soon as it's created (since the Python object it is based off is never kept around)

I think these issues can be addressed with something like

```
cdef char* line_ptr
for line in f: # line IS NOT TYPED
  line_ba = bytearray(line) # bytearray is mutable - changing it is fine
  line_ptr = line_ba # line_ptr is valid as long as line_ba exists
```

Both your code and my suggested replacement has a lot of conversions between Python and C strings, which is never hugely fast (and difficult to get right). It looks like the sort of thing that would be simplest to just write in Python - I doubt you're really benefiting from the C calls.

Comment: I think `strtok` changes `line` - it puts `\0` where needed. That however has the potential to change immutable Python bytes. I guess in the most cases it doesn’t happen, because `line` is a dangling pointer - nothing holds a reference of the original bytes-object, so it is probably already destructed at this point - thus the crashes (not 100% sure about this though). Yet this is a problem for bytes-objects which are interned.

Comment: Using python for parsing is a very good advice. It would be interesting to see whether there is potential for C to be faster.

Comment: @ead You're right about it changing `line`. That's another disaster waiting to happen but does invalidate my second point. You're also right about `line` and the dangling pointer - I missed that. I suspect C could be faster, but I dislike working with C strings enough that it won't be me that makes it faster :)